# Error Magento 2 : Stores > Configuration : Error log record number: 1434336705656 / Items Not Displaying

Tags: magento, magento2, bitnami

When I'm trying to open the "Stores > Configuration" it says:

> There has been an error processing your request: Error log record number: 1434336705656"

and it doesn't display any other stuff.

I've been facing this problem since I uploaded 1 New Theme and 5 new Extensions and due to this I'm unable to configure Theme and other extension settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a live server, then login via ssh details and run the following commands from  theroot folder of your Magento installation:

The following command remove static content from Magento 2

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* var/view_preprocessed/ var/*cache/*
```

Follow these steps to create content for your site

1. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
2. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
3. make sure Apache's "rewrite_module" is enabled and then restart the server
4. Delete the cache folder under var/cache